# Addition formula for $\text{sn}(u)=\text{sn}(u,k)$

Tags: elliptic-integrals, elliptic-functions

I have just learned the definition of the first Jacobian elliptic function $\text{sn}(u)=\text{sn}(u,k)$, defined as the sine of the inverse function of
$$F(\phi,k):=\int_0^\phi \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(x)}}$$
with respect to $\phi$; that is, if $u=F(\phi,k)$, then $\text{sn}(u,k)=\sin\phi$. I also know the analogous definitions of $\text{cn}(u,k)$ and $\text{dn}(u,k)$.

**QUESTION.** I have seen the following addition formula and would like to know how to prove it:
$$\text{sn}(u+v)=\frac{\text{sn}(u)\text{cn}(v)\text{dn}(v)+\text{sn}(v)\text{cn}(u)\text{dn}(u)}{1-k^2\text{sn}^2(u)\text{sn}^2(v)}$$
How is this formula proven? Does it require any "advanced machinery" that a beginner would not be familiar with, or is it a simple proof?

Comment: Maybe not with all the details you are asking for but pages 4,5,6,7,8 of [this](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1148&context=rhumj) seem to be helpful. It looks like there is a result which is true of a broader class of functions and this is just an application of this.

Comment: @Mason Wow, that's great! That is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: I am glad it helped. I am still trying to parse through the details. Somehow the equation on the bottom of page 6 is to be transformed into what you have given above. It would be good to write how this happens exactly.

Comment: @Mason Well, if I can work out the details then I will post it as an answer to my own question.

Comment: This is a very standard result and is presented in most textbooks which cover elliptic functions. You may also have a look at [my post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/01/elliptic-functions-addition-formulas.html?m=0) based on Cayley's book.

Comment: In general no advanced machinery is needed to understand elliptic functions unless you want to study its link with algebraic number theory. For me this link has been so notoriously difficult.